# Code blocks are not explained in chat faq

Tags: feature-request, code-block, chat-faq

While looking over [the stackoverflow chat faq](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) I noticed that it does not explain how to use code blocks when multi line is used.

It would be nice if there was a little description for users about how the `fixed font` button appears after shift+enter has been used, or that they can use ctrl+k to get the same result as clicking the `fixed font` button.

[image]

Comment: Does anyone even read the FAQs?

Comment: @nhahtdh I remember clicking a lot of links and getting a badge, but that was about it.

Comment: @nhahtdh I read the chat FAQ, but only because it's more like an instruction manual for some of the less obvious features.

Comment: @nhahtdh it's my favorite destination on a new site, after About.

Comment: i didn't know about ctrl-k ....